# One event handler allowed per DOM on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

I am trying to learn Javascript, and want to clarify event handling by inline vs traditional registration.

When I execute the following code in Chrome, two alert messages are displayed -
helloAgain() then hello(). 
-I thought only one event handler can be assigned to a DOM?

If I move javascript code to after , only one alert message helloAgain() is displayed.

-Since hello() comes before helloAgain(), shouldn't hello() be executed based on the order? Why doesn't helloAgain() execute?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

//<![CDATA
function hello(){
    var hello = "hello!"
    alert(hello)
    console.log(this)
}

function helloAgain(){
    var hello= "Hello One More time"
    alert(hello)
}
window.onload = helloAgain
//]]
</script>
</head>

<body onload="hello()">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To DOM you can add multiple event listeners, but in your case, `body` and `window` are different objects.

Comment: Are you talking about putting Javascript after your dom?  I am having some issues understanding the last sentence/paragraph

Comment: Sorry, I revised my post.

Comment: If you're just starting to learn JS, maybe better to start with [something modern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) ; ).

Comment: @Teemu: but why doesn't another method execute when I move javascript to after DOM (ie. after <body></body>? Thanks.

Comment: @user3562812 There should be only `</html>` after `</body>`, invalid HTML is not guaranteed to be parsed correctly. If you'll put the event listener for `body` outside, parser finds the script after the `body.onload` has been fired (which is fired when parser meets the closing `body` tag).

Comment: @Teemu: My bad. Thanks for the explanation. So, javascript code placed in side <head></head> is parsed different from when placed inside <body></body>

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `head`, it is guaranteed to be fully parsed and all executables in it executed before start parsing `body`.